# Sheets GAS editor, trying to form an array, reduce to combine it/sum values and then reprint it, cant build 2D Array of final data

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Starting out in JS.
I tried to be concise in the title, couldnt.
I have some data in a sheet:

[image: DATA IN QUESTION]

What I want and have somewhat accomplished, is to do two things

group by id and sum the qty, reformat the pr column by product, just a name. I'll try to make the code reproducible right here, so it's easier to catch the error (I might solve it without asking, :O, I'll leave this)

```js
  //var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("SortProductos");
  var a = [[ 66 ],[ 66 ],[ 66 ],[ 66 ],[ 66 ],[ 24 ],[ 330 ],[ 155 ],[ 127 ],[ 110 ],[ 272 ],[ 272 ],[ 272 ],[ 272 ],[ 272 ],[ 70 ],[ 78 ]];
  var b = [ [ 1 ],[ 1 ],[ 1 ],[ 1 ],[ 1 ],[ 2 ],[ 2 ],[ 1 ],[ 1 ],[ 1 ],[ 1 ],[ 1 ],[ 2 ],[ 1 ],[ 1 ],  [ 1 ],[ 1 ] ];
  var c = [ [ 'PD-1346' ],[ 'PD-1000-B' ],[ 'PD-1028' ],[ 'PD-711' ],[ 'PD-58' ],[ 'PD-1445' ],[ 'PD-860' ],[ 'PD-648' ],[ 'PD-1483' ],[ 'PD-1044' ],[ 'PD-58' ],[ 'PD-65' ],[ 'PD-1499' ],[ 'PD-368' ],[ 'PD-465' ],[ 'PD-73B' ],[ 'PD-1469' ] ];

  var pNameF = [];

  for (let i=0; i<c.length;i++) {
    var temp = c[i][0];
    if (temp.startsWith('PD-')) {
       pNameF.push('FRASLE') 
      } 
  }

  const data = a.map(function(a, indice) {
    return {
      id: a[0],
      qty: b[indice][0],
      pName: pNameF[indice][0],      
    }
  })
  console.log(data);


  
  const inputVal = [
    ...data.reduce(
      (map, item) => {
        const { id: key, qty } = item;
        const prev = map.get(key);
        
        if(prev) {
          prev.qty += qty
        } else {
          map.set(key, Object.assign({}, item))
        }
        
        return map
      },
      new Map()
    ).values()
  ]

  console.log(inputVal)

  const inputFinal = [];

  for (let i=0; i<inputVal.length; i++) {
    let id = inputVal[i][0];
    let qty = inputVal[i][1];
    let prodN = inputVal[i][2];

    inputFinal.push([id, qty, prodN])
  }

  console.log(inputFinal);
```

So, problems that arise, a couple:
First off, IDK why the arr.map just catches the first letter of the whole word instead of the entire string???? talking about the var = pNameF

But let's ignore that, the reduce does it job but I have to reconvert that to a 2-d array for google sheets if not, I can't use .setValues();

Yet the for says undefined which I'm guessing means the const inputVal isn't filled?? but how? if I log it just before and it shows the content.

I'm sure there are better ways to do all of this but I'm trying to do stuff with what I kinda understand reduce being the least understood and map close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issues:

**First**: `pNameF` is a 1D array so accessing the index then further getting the `[0]` gets you the `F` instead of `FRASLE`.

To fix this, modify:

```
pNameF.push('FRASLE')
```

To:

```
pNameF.push(['FRASLE'])
```

or just remove the `[0]` when accessing the value.

**Next**: You are trying to access `inputVal` like it is a 2D array, but it is not. It's an array of object. You need to access the keys per element instead.

From:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < inputVal.length; i++) {
    let id = inputVal[i][0];
    let qty = inputVal[i][1];
    let prodN = inputVal[i][2];

    inputFinal.push([id, qty, prodN])
  }
```

To:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < inputVal.length; i++) {
    let id = inputVal[i].id;
    let qty = inputVal[i].qty;
    let prodN = inputVal[i].pName;

    inputFinal.push([id, qty, prodN])
  }
```

#### Script Output:

[image: final output]

You should now be able to use this to `setValues()`

```
sheet.getRange(1, 1, inputFinal.length, inputFinal[0].length).setValues(inputFinal);
```

[image: output]